# Tricky sequence proof?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose that $\langle{{a_{n}}}\rangle$ is a sequence that is nondecreasing and bounded above. Let A = $\langle{{a_{n}}}\rangle$.

1. Show that A has a supremum.
   (Isn't this already obvious b/c A is bounded above? Therefore it must have a supremum?)
2. Let $\alpha=supA$. Prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_{n}}=\alpha$. That is, that $\langle{{a_{n}}}\rangle$ converges.

For this second part, I was thinking of using the formal definition of convergence (i.e. using epsilon-delta inequalities) but am stuck on how to set up the limit. Thoughts and ideas are welcome! Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\alpha=\sup_n a_n$, we have
$$\tag{1}
a_n \le \alpha \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N},
$$
and given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists some $N= N(\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$
\alpha-\varepsilon < a_N.
$$
Using the fact that $\{a_n\}$ is nondecreasing, it follows that
$$\tag{2}
\alpha-\varepsilon < a_n \quad \forall n \ge N.
$$
Combining (1) and (2) we get
$$
\alpha-\varepsilon < a_n < \alpha+\varepsilon \quad \forall n \ge N,
$$
i.e. $\lim_na_n=\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

For each $\epsilon>0$, by definition of $\sup$, $\alpha-\epsilon$ isn't a upper bound of the set, so $\exists n_\epsilon$ s.t. $a_{n_\epsilon}>\alpha-\epsilon$. And now, for $n>n_\epsilon$:
$$\alpha-\epsilon<a_{n_\epsilon}\le a_n<\alpha+\epsilon.$$

Answer (score 1):

Fix $\epsilon>0$.
By the definition of a supremum, we may state that there is an $N$ such that 
$$
\alpha - \epsilon < a_N < \alpha
$$
We may certainly state that $|a_N - \alpha| < \epsilon$.  In order to prove convergence using its definition, we'd have to say that for all $n>N$, $|a_n - \alpha| < \epsilon$ is also true.  Why is this the case?